# Handling alert box without starting a new driver

Tags: python, selenium

The piece of code below used to work, by including the url security (username + password) to the server within the url before would handle the alert.

An update came along and now it fails, the page is loaded up and THEN the alert is displayed, the ordering is now incorrect.

I would like to handle the problem here. I usually access elements in this file and send text/clicks to each element specifically. Because it's a dialog box, there are no elements to access.

Declaring a new driver opens a new page which isn't what I want.

```
def load_website(self, driver_init):
    url_protocol = settings['url_protocol']
    url_resource_name = settings['url_resource_name']
    url_security = settings['url_security']

    if url_security != "":
        url_sec = url_protocol+url_security+url_resource_name
        driver_init.get(url_sec)
        print("Navigated to URL: " + url_sec)

    url = url_protocol+url_resource_name
    driver_init.get(url)
    print("Navigated to URL: " + url)
```

Error message:

Dismissed user prompt dialog: https://exampleurl.com is requesting your username and password.

selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py:241: UnexpectedAlertPresentException

Comment: you can set some drivers to handle unexpected alerts, but it seems like you need to login here.  Are you just trying to auto-accept/dismiss the alert or did you want to handle it before the unexpected alert exception is thrown?  Also what driver are you using here?

Comment: The alert was handled alone. It's not too bad, I know I can .send_keys to tab and press enter too, it's just getting access to the thing!

Answer (score 0):

For python: https://www.techbeamers.com/handle-alert-popup-selenium-python/

```
driver.switch_to.alert
```

For Java: https://www.guru99.com/alert-popup-handling-selenium.html

```
    Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
```